# Can't call with tpqoa

Tags: python-3.x, rest, wrapper

Can someone help me with this error?
Is there an error in my pyalgo file?
What type of other address I have to put into tpqoa call?

CODE

pyalgo.cfg

```
 [oanda]
    account_id = "101-012-21240417-001"
    access_token = 'hidden'
    account_type = practice
```

CODE

```
import oandapyV20
import pandas as pd
import tpqoa
api = tpqoa.tpqoa('../pyalgo.cfg')
api.get.instruments()[:15]
```

Output

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_5064/836215391.py in <module>
      2 import pandas as pd
      3 import tpqoa
----> 4 api = tpqoa.tpqoa('../pyalgo.cfg')
      5 from oandapyV20 import API
      6 import oandapyV20.endpoints.pricing as pricing

~\anaconda3\envs\PythonPC\lib\site-packages\tpqoa\tpqoa.py in __init__(self, conf_file)
    111         self.config = configparser.ConfigParser()
    112         self.config.read(conf_file)
--> 113         self.access_token = self.config['oanda']['access_token']
    114         self.account_id = self.config['oanda']['account_id']
    115         self.account_type = self.config['oanda']['account_type']

~\anaconda3\envs\PythonPC\lib\configparser.py in __getitem__(self, key)
    958     def __getitem__(self, key):
    959         if key != self.default_section and not self.has_section(key):
--> 960             raise KeyError(key)
    961         return self._proxies[key]
    962 

KeyError: 'oanda'
```

Answer (score 0):

you have indented the account_id, access_token and account_type.

unindent them then run it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).